# iOS: Make layer opaque without fading text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios5

I have a frame on my UIView with a layer. I have the layer set the background color and make the alpha 0.5 and make the frame.backgroundColor = clearColor so that people can see the lines behind it. However it makes the subviews which hold text also faded out. How do I prevent this?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setAlpha:kAlpha];
        CALayer *layer = [self layer];
        [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
        [layer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

        tileTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        tileTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        tileTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tileTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f];

        tileDescription = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        tileDescription.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        tileDescription.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tileDescription.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f];
        tileDescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;

        [self addSubview:tileTitle];
        [self addSubview:tileDescription];
    }

    return self;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the transparency of the view, but not its subviews, you can change its background color:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.25];
```

This method also works with a CALayer.

Answer (score 1):

you must not set alpha value on all uiview, you must se the color with alfa.

```
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subview (with the same size as your UIView) and set the color and alpha on the subview to your desired tranparency, rather than setting the alpha of your view.  Set the backgroundColor of the top-level UIView to clearColor.